# Doctrine - Hydrate collection in Entity class

Tags: php, symfony, collections, doctrine-orm

I have a problem regarding a bi-directional `OneToMany <-> ManyToOne` relationship between my entities `Device` and `Event`. This is how mapping looks:

```
// Device entity
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Event", mappedBy="device")
     */
    protected $events;


// Event entity
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Device", inversedBy="events")
     */
    protected $device;
```

The problem comes because `Device` is a *Single Table Inheritance* entity

```
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="device_class_type", type="string")
```

and each time I fetch and iterate over some `Event` entities, then `$device` is always eagerly fetched. This happens because it's a STI entity as reported in [related documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#performance-impact)

> There is a general performance consideration with Single Table
> Inheritance: If the target-entity of a many-to-one or one-to-one
> association is an STI entity, it is preferable for performance reasons
> that it be a leaf entity in the inheritance hierarchy, (ie. have no
> subclasses). Otherwise Doctrine CANNOT create proxy instances of this
> entity and will ALWAYS load the entity eagerly.

Now there's another entity called `Gateway` which has relationships with both `Device` and `Event`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Device", mappedBy="gateway")
 */
protected $devices;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Event", mappedBy="gateway")
 */
protected $events;


public function getEvents(): Collection
{
    return $this->events;
}
```

And of course each time I iterate over `$gateway->getEvents()` all related events devices are fetched eagerly. This happens even if I don't get any `$device` info - an empty `foreach` is enough to let Doctrine execute 1 query for each object to fetch related `$device`

```
foreach ($gateway->getEvents() as $event) {}
```

Now I know I could use `QueryBuilder` to set a different hydration mode avoiding `$device` fetching

```
return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('e')
            ->from('AppBundle:Event', 'e')
            ->where('e.gateway = :gateway')
            ->setParameter('gateway', $gateway)
            ->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_SIMPLEOBJECT);
```

but I would like to do it somehow directly in `Gateway` entity.

So is it possible hydrate `Gateway->events` directly in `Gateway` entity class?

Comment: You can use 'INSTANCE OF' on your DQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You'll need to [write your own hydration method](http://doctrine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/manual/data-hydrators.html#writing-hydration-method)

You have a cyclical reference where one of those nodes (Device) will force a `FETCH EAGER`. Making matters worse, one of those nodes (Gateway) is acting like ManyToMany join table between the other two, resulting in `FETCH EAGER` loading everything in an near-infinite loop (or at least large blocks of related data).

```
 +──<   OneToMany
 >──+   ManyToOne
 >──<   ManyToMany
 +──+   OneToOne

       ┌──────< Gateway >──────┐
       │                       │
       +                       +
     Event +──────────────< Device*
```

As you can see, when device does an EAGER fetch, it will collect many `Gateways`, thus many `Events`, thus many `Devices`, thus many more `Gateways`, etc. `Fetch EAGER` will keep going until all references are populated.

#### Prevent "EAGER" Hydration, by building your own Hydrator.

Building your own hydrator will require some careful data-manipulation, but will likely be somewhat simple for your use case. Remember to register your hydrator with Doctrine, and pass it as an argument to `$query->execute([], 'GatewayHydrator');`

```
class GatewayHydrator extends DefaultEntityHydrator
{
    public function hydrateResultSet($stmt)
    {
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $class = $this->em->getClassMetadata(Gateway::class);
        $gateway = $class->newInstance();

        $gateway->setName($data[0]['gateway_name']); // example only

        return $gateway;
    }
}
```

#### Alternatively, Remove the Mapped Field from Device to Gateway

Removing the `$gateway => Gateway` mapping from `Device`, and `mappedBy="gateway"` from the `Gateway->device` mapping, Device would effectively become a leaf from Doctrine's perspective. This would avoid that reference loop, with one drawback: the Device->gateway property would have to be manually set (perhaps in the Gateway and Event `setDevice` methods).

Comment: I really appreciate your effort but this still doesn't answer the current question, namely if it's possible to do it directly in entity class without `QueryBuilder`. Anyway thank you for your answer.

Comment: @DrKey, check the last section of my answer: "Remove the Mapped Field". This is the only way to resolve your problem by only editing the Entity classes.

Comment: @DrKey, the point here, is that your premise for the question (with existing field mappings), negates any resolution supported by existing Hydrators. You either must change the premise (mappings), or the hydrator.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you couple of options to consider here.

1) As per [Doctrine's documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetomany%20%22Doctrine's%20documentation) you can use `fetch="EAGER"` to hint Doctrine that you want the relation eagerly fetched whenever the entity is being loaded:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Device", mappedBy="gateway", fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $devices;
```

If used carefully this can save you from firing additional queries upon iteration but has it's own drawbacks either.

If you start to extensively use forced eager loading you may find yourself in situation where loading an entity to read a simple attribute from it will result in loading tens and even hundreds of relations. This may not look as bad from SQL point of view (perhaps a single query) but remember that all the results will be hydrated as objects and attached to the Unit Of Work to monitor them for changes.

2) If you are using this for reporting purposes (e.g. display all events for a device) then it's better not to use entities at all but to request array hydration from Doctrine. In this case you will be able to control what gets into the result by explicitly joining the relation (or not). As an added benefit you'll skip the expensive hydration and monitoring by the UoM as it's unlikely to modify entities in such a case. This is considered a "best practice" too when using Doctrine for reporting.

Comment: Of course I know that I could left join table to avoid multiple queries but still hydration needs resources. And I know how to change hydration using entity manager, but I would do it directly in entity class. By the way thank you for your answer.

Comment: You are welcome. Btw I'm not really sure what you mean by "directly in entity class" but Doctrine is a Data Mapper implementation and as such puts emphasis on extracting the persistence logic *outside* the entity (in contrast to e.g. Active Record). So by design one is not supposed to "fetch" from "inside". The closest you can get to "inside" is by altering Doctrine's behavior. The out of the box method is by using the `fetch="EAGER"` in entity's mapping. If you need something more complex then perhaps you should dive into Doctrine internals and provide custom hydrator and/or proxies.